# Compile and run assembly file using Masm and ConTEXT

Tags: assembly, configuration, compiler-construction, masm, context-editor

I have to compile some assembly filed but I really don't know how to do that...
I successfully installed Masm on my computer and also ConTEXT editor that I use to write assembly files.
Unfortunately, buttons to compile, run and debug must be set in ConTEXT to be used but I don't know how to tell him to compile using masm32 installed at `C:\masm32`.

LAST THING: are there any other simple IDE to work with assembly and compile without the DOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MASM32 come with its own editor QEditor, but the following are good IDE's
[RadASM](http://radasm.cherrytree.at/)
[WinASM](http://www.winasm.net/) (open source)
[EasyCode](http://www.easycode.cat/English/index.htm) (kinda like VB)

Answer (score 2):

The process is much easier to accomplish with the command line. Here are the basic commands you should use:

```
ml /c /coff /FoMyAssembly.obj MyAssembly.asm
@if errorlevel 1 pause
link /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS MyAssembly.obj
@if errorlevel 1 pause
```

Where "MyAssembly.asm" is your source file. What would even easier would be to use a batch file like the one I've written:

```
@if not exist %1.rc goto NoResource

  rc /foRes.res %1.rc
  cvtres /machine:ix86 /out:Res.obj Res.res
  del Res.res
  @if errorlevel 1 pause

  ml /c /coff /Fo%1.obj %1
  @if errorlevel 1 pause
  link /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS %1.obj res.obj
  @if errorlevel 1 pause
  del %1.obj
  del res.obj

  C:\upx.exe -qq %1.exe

@goto Exit

:NoResource
  ml /c /coff /Fo%1.obj %1
  @if errorlevel 1 pause
  link /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS %1.obj
  @if errorlevel 1 pause
  del %1.obj

:Exit
```

Right click on the source file and choose: "Open With...", this batch file will do all the work for you.